# How to troubleshoot JS dependencies between webjars and scala-js jars in an SBT project?

Tags: javascript, sbt, scala.js, webjars, scalajs-react

I've been using scalajs-dom v 0.8.1 and trying to mix webjars within my SBT project.  When I do this, I'm getting one final ambiguous JS reference that I can't figure out.  I think it is between the webjars I want to use (that include jquery v 2.1.4) and scala-js.  I tried using the ManifestFilters SBT filter but it does not seem to help (or I don't know the correct syntax).  Does anyone have a useful way to debug these kinds of errors?  (see below for SBT output when issuing the 'fastOptJS' task)

```
[error] - Ambiguous reference to a JS library: jquery.js
[error]   Possible paths found on the classpath:
[error]   - META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/dist/jquery.js
[error]   - META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/src/jquery.js
[error]   originating from: spJS:compile, spJS:compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the specific subpath for jquery.js should disambiguate when pulling down webjar dependencies.

```
jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "dist/jquery.js"
```

see: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1496

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  Unfortunately it did not work for me.  I was trying to use a fancy file upload library that needed org.webjars.bower components and so I was trying the bower version of jquery.  Maybe that has something to do with it (I don't know how bower works--all I know is by finding 'bower' versions of webjars, the ambiguities went away except for the jquery one).  Thanks for your help.