# Ambiguous reference to a JS library: jquery.js

Tags: jquery, scala.js, webjars

ScalaJS

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.9")
```

with (after included jquery-ui dep):

```
libraryDependencies += "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.0",
jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % 2.2.3 / "jquery.js",
jsDependencies += "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery-ui" % "1.11.4" / "draggable.js"
```

error on compile with fastOptJS:

```
[error] - Ambiguous reference to a JS library: jquery.js
[error]   Possible paths found on the classpath:
[error]   - META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js
[error]   - META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/src/jquery.js
[error]   - META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/dist/jquery.js
```

I've tried with this thread:
[How to resolve "Ambiguous reference to a JS library"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756676/how-to-resolve-ambiguous-reference-to-a-js-library) and this [How to troubleshoot JS dependencies between webjars and scala-js jars in an SBT project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169278/how-to-troubleshoot-js-dependencies-between-webjars-and-scala-js-jars-in-an-sbt)

but that have not helped me (yet)

**UPDATED: My Build Project with all deps defined**

```
object BuildProject extends Build {

lazy val myPluginProject = Project(id = "my-site", base = file(".")).

settings(   

 version      := "0.1",
 scalaVersion := Versions.scala,

 ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) },

 libraryDependencies += "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.0" exclude("org.webjars","jquery"),
 libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %%% "upickle" % Versions.upickle,

 libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % Versions.scalaTags,

 // we will not use use DOM directly so commenting it
 libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % Versions.dom,


 jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % Versions.jquery / "jquery.js",

 jsDependencies += "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery-ui" % Versions.jqueryUI / "draggable.js",

  jsDependencies += "org.webjars.bower" % "webcomponents.js" % Versions.webcomponents / "webcomponents-lite.js",

 skip in packageJSDependencies := false,

 jsDependencies += RuntimeDOM,

 scalaJSUseRhino in Global := false ) .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)}
```

where

```
  val dom = "0.9.0"
  val upickle = "0.4.0"
  val jquery = "2.2.3"
  val jqueryUI = "1.11.4"
  val webcomponents = "0.7.21"
```

**UPDATE 2** - "2.2.3/jquery.js" + dependsON

```
  jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % Versions.jquery / "2.2.3/jquery.js",

 jsDependencies += "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery-ui" % Versions.jqueryUI / "core.js" dependsOn "META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js",
```

Then:

```
[error]   Possible paths found on the classpath:
[error]   - META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery-ui/1.11.4/ui/core.js
[error]   - META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/src/core.js
```

**UPDATE 3** - "1.11.4/core.js"
If:

```
   jsDependencies += "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery-ui" % Versions.jqueryUI / "1.11.4/core.js" dependsOn "META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js",
```

then:

```
[error] (compile:resolvedJSDependencies) org.scalajs.core.tools.jsdep.JSLibResolveException: Some references to JS libraries could not be resolved: [error] - Missing JS library:
1.11.4/core.js
```

**UPDATE:**

from the web-jar pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
<version>1.11.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I do not see that it would depend on jquery 2.2.3 ...

--

> as a user, i guess will wait couple of years to make it mature.

Comment: Hmm.  What other dependencies do you have?  It looks like something's pulling in 3.0.0...

Comment: Hello ses, have you found an answer for your question?

Comment: https://github.com/Sergey80/scalajs_bug - created a bug in the repo to test

Answer (score 4):

Your dependency

```
jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % 2.2.3 / "jquery.js"
```

is ambiguous, because there are several files matching the suffix `jquery.js` on your classpath. You can use a longer suffix to disambiguate them, for example:

```
jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % 2.2.3 / "2.2.3/jquery.js"
```

which will only match the path

```
META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js
```

Comment: Re `1.11.4/core.js`, look at the paths in the ambiguous error, it should be `1.11.4/ui/core.js` or more simply `ui/core.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Just made use of another jquery-ui that has draggbale in it.

```
 jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % Versions.jquery / "jquery.js",
 jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery-ui" % "1.11.4" / "jquery-ui.js" dependsOn "jquery.js"
```

And the way I use:

```
val containerDyn  = jQuery("#launcher-main-container")
containerDyn.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].draggable()
```

And not sure why it pulled `3.0.0-beta1` dep